# Combing effect while reading interlaced video

Tags: opencv, video-capture, mpeg2-ts

all. I have a very strange issue, reading the VideoCapture in OpenCV.
I have .MTS videos (MPEG2), and I read them in OpenCV using the next code:

```
cv2.namedWindow("frame", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("00030.MTS")

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And this shows me the corrupted frames (with bands on them). The same quality is kept, if I save the frame as the image, and look at It outside the OpenCV.
[image]

But how It should look like:
[image]
I've never seen this before while working with .avi or .mp4

How can I get the same not-corrupted frames like in the media player?

Comment: That combing looks like a frame ordering issue. Somehow, you are mixing up progressive or interlaced. Or the frames are second/first instead of first/second. It could also be 24P pulldown related.

Comment: most likely it's just interlaced footage. interlaced footage is always a hassle. ffmpeg/opencv shows it to you as one frame that contains both fields. hence the combs. you should preprocess your footage using ffmpeg: apply a deinterlacing filter. `yadif` is a popular and good choice. VLC detects interlaced video and automatically applies a suitable filter. ffmpeg knows the video is interlaced, but it doesn't automatically apply filters (because they're costly and change the data).

Comment: if you showed the video 1:1, you'd see per-pixel "combs". when you resize that, you get additional resampling, which results in a type of moire pattern or interference. that's the "larger scale" patterns you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I edited the title of the question. Some of this information wasn't apparent originally.)*

Your file names suggest that this video material is a video camera's own recording, with no alterations to it.

Your video seems to be "interlaced", i.e. not "progressive". Interlaced video consists of "fields" instead of complete frames. A field contains all the even or odd *lines* of an image. Even and odd fields follow each other. With that method, you can have "50i" video that updates at 50 Hz, yet requires only half the data of a full "50p" video (half the data means reduced vertical resolution).

OpenCV (probably) uses ffmpeg to read your video file.

Both ffmpeg and VLC know when a video file contains interlaced video data. VLC automatically applies a suitable filter to make this data nicer to look at. ffmpeg does not, because filtering costs processing time and changes the data.

You should use ffmpeg to "de-interlace" your video files. I would suggest the [`yadif` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#yadif-1).

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i 00001.MTS -c copy -vf yadif -c:v libx264 -b:v 24M 00001_deinterlaced.MTS
```

You should look at the [settings/options of yadif](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#yadif-1). Maybe the defaults aren't to your liking. Try `yadif=1` to get field-rate progressive video (50/60p).